# navigate between f# and c# projects

Tags: visual-studio, f#

Is it possible to setup visual studio so that i can go to definition between c# and f# projects? does anybody know of any plans to make better integration for f# in visual studio?

Comment: I took liberty to open a Microsoft Connect suggestion at https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/667141/should-be-able-to-go-to-definition-from-f-project-to-c-project

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not a supported operation in Visual Studio.  In general Go To Definition, Find All References, etc ... does not work between projects of different languages.  This is true for any combination of C++, C#, F# and VB.Net

If you want to tell Microsoft this is a feature you desire then please vote for [this Microsoft Connect item](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/667141/should-be-able-to-go-to-definition-from-f-project-to-c-project)

Comment: ahh, ok, that sucks, especially considering that there are less reasons to mix vb.net and c# in a solution on a new product, but mixing c# with f# would seem more frequent (UI in c# and back-end in f#, for example). I can also see a lot of examples where one would mix C++ and and of the other languages...ok, thanks

Comment: @Alek yeah it does suck. My VsVim project has a core F# engine with a C# wrapper that does the WPF and Visual Studio integration. Definitely sucks navigating between them.

Comment: I was convinced I'd done something wrong which stopped this working. I'm both relieved and disappointed to find out it wasn't me!